# calling variable in blade from external file

Tags: php, laravel

I'm filling my html blade with an html table that's populated by queries in another file.

It all shows fine except for one variable that's created out of the main function that performs those queries and I'm simply trying to call it from the blade.

Everything I have now works as far as returning query results and wrapping them so that I can put them into my html view. It all displays except for this one column which is in another function in the origin file.

Basically I just need to call the $percent variable from numbersfile.php into a column in my html view

NumbersFile.php

```
function totals(){

    $total = $row['total'];
    $sales = $row['sales'];
    $percent = round( ($total / $sales) * 100, 2 );
    //all of this data is correct

}
```

report.php

```
function percentReport($p){

    $data = [];

    $totals = new NumbersFile();
    $totals->doQuery($p[0]);
    $totals->fetchData();

    while ($row = $totals->fetchRow()) {
        $summary[] = $row;
    }
    $data = $summary;
    $wrap['data'] = $data;
    return $wrap; // this returns everything I need from the original query

}
```

numbers.blade.php

```
@foreach($data['data'] as $td)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$td['total1']}}</td>
        <td>{{$td['total2']}}</td>
        <td>{{$td['total3']}}</td>
        <td>{{$td['total4']}}</td> <!--These rows show perfectly fine-->
        <td>{{$percent}}</td><!--This is what I need to fill with that variable-->
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Show us how you include / require the files and how $data is set.

Comment: it's not node.js, hat's not how it works. you need to require that file with composer

Comment: You might check variable scoping before using a function's variable outside it's scope.

Answer (score 0):

why not using `@include` inside blade ?

```
@include('{your path}/{your file name without .php extension}')
```

And make sure `$percent` is accessible outside the `totals( )` function (care about encapsulation).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a "helper" file, I usually have app/Http/helpers.php, you need to add it on composer.json

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "files":["app/Http/helpers.php"]
},
```

run composer update

You need to move that function inside the helpers.php or add each file inside the composer, also the totals function must return $percent, and i think you need to send the variables to that function.

and then on your view

```
{{ totals() }}
```

Why you have the file "report.php"? I think it's better to do it on the controller and then send it to the view.